# A way of checking if a paypal transaction was made

Tags: c#, asp.net, paypal

I'm trying to find a way of implementing the paypal api in my asp.net project.

Basically, what I'm trying to achieve is to create a page where the user sends the money and a page where the payment is checked.

I wasn't able to find a way of checking the payment.

It's an important step in my project because I need to check if the payment was made in order to insert some data into a SQL database and I don't want the database to be exploited using the payment/checking method.

Can someone guide me?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: this link has a detailed explanation and sample : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/42894/Introduction-to-PayPal-for-C-ASP-NET-developers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you are looking for [PayPal IPN (Instant Payment Notification)](https://www.paypal.com/ipn). It is intended for exactly this purpose.

Essentially, PayPal will call a special page/handler on your site and assert that the transaction has completed successfully and it is safe to release a product to your user. You can trust this call because of the manner in which the handshake occurs.

### Sample IPN Handler

<sup>This code comes straight from the [PayPal docs](https://www.x.com/developers/PayPal/documentation-tools/code-sample/216623), but I have implemented a variation of it myself and can validate that it works "as advertised".</sup>

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;

public partial class csIPNexample : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Post back to either sandbox or live
        string strSandbox = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        string strLive = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(strSandbox);

        //Set values for the request back
        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        byte[] param = Request.BinaryRead(HttpContext.Current.Request.ContentLength);
        string strRequest = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(param);
        strRequest += "&cmd=_notify-validate";
        req.ContentLength = strRequest.Length;

        //for proxy
        //WebProxy proxy = new WebProxy(new Uri("http://url:port#"));
        //req.Proxy = proxy;

        //Send the request to PayPal and get the response
        StreamWriter streamOut = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), System.Text.Encoding.ASCII);
        streamOut.Write(strRequest);
        streamOut.Close();
        StreamReader streamIn = new StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream());
        string strResponse = streamIn.ReadToEnd();
        streamIn.Close();

        if (strResponse == "VERIFIED")
        {
            //check the payment_status is Completed
            //check that txn_id has not been previously processed
            //check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
            //check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
            //process payment
        }
        else if (strResponse == "INVALID")
        {
            //log for manual investigation
        }
        else
        {
            //log response/ipn data for manual investigation
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this sample but there's something I can't understand. This page is the one where the user is redirected after he made the payment? and the page will take the data needed from the url ?

Comment: Actually, the user never sees this page. It is only used for PayPal to notify you so that you can perform post-payment actions. I believe that an IPN handler is *only* needed if you are redirecting the user to PayPal's site to receive payment info (i.e. not collecting it on your own site).

Comment: So , after he made the payment , paypal will call my page and post the ipn of the payment so I can check the payment in the page load?

Comment: 1) User makes payment on paypal's site. 2) paypal sends a message to your site (the IPN page) independent of the user. This usually happens within a few seconds, but it's not always immediate. 3) Once you receive that message, you know that the transaction is complete.

Comment: and this method can't be exploited? I mean , the user can get the ipn of the payment and lets say he found the page where I'm checking the payment and posts the value. or there's no way of finding the ipn of his own payment?

Comment: The IPN isn't just a number...it's a notification sequence where PayPal calls your site, you respond, and they confirm. Because of this handshake, it would be nearly impossible to exploit.

Comment: Oh I understand,but how can I send a certain string along with the IPN so I can check the type of the payment based on the string value

Comment: There are hidden field(s) that you can pass along with the initial request that is submitted to PayPal, which will then be sent back to you with the IPN message. I looked at some code of mine from a few years ago, and the field was just called "custom" and you could put whatever you wanted in it.